# Logging in Activity, postOnExecute, Resume

Tags: android, android-asynctask, onresume, autologin

I need to implement auto-login process from an activity. Also I need to show `ProgressDialog` while logging in. I use `AsyncTask` for login process, because I haven't succeeded to show `ProgressDialog` in other way, and I execute the mentioned `AsyncTask` in `onCreate`. I read that all the code which is executed after `doInBackground` must be written in `onPostExecute`, but I have code in `onResume`. The `onResume` is launched when `AsyncTask` hasn't finished its execution yet. Is it possible to launch `onResume` only after `AsyncTask` is finished? Or is it possible to execute other functions after `AsyncTask` is finished (in general)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Is it possible to launch onResume only after AsyncTask is finished?
```

No, you need to follow the `Activity Lifecycle`. And the `AsyncTask` is asynchronous so that it can run while your `UI` can still do other things. What you can do is put the code that is in `onResume()` that you want to run after the task has finished in your `onPostExecute()` method. There are other options but without seeing the code you are trying to run, this would be my suggestion.

> Or is it possible to execute other functions after AsyncTask is finished (in general)?

Yes. You can put that code in another `Activity` method and call that from `onPostExecute()`

You also can use `getStatus()` method of `AsyncTask` to run code based on the [Status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html) of your `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No.

If you check the [developer android website](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) or [this image](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png), you'll check that `OnResume()` after the Activity is loaded, either after created, paused or restarted. In my case, I have that verification done in `OnResume()`.